# webRequest.onHeadersReceived is not triggered with local files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When using this snippet, it should log the headers when loading a `file://..` url too but it only does for http(s) requests.

```
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((info) => {
    console.log(info);
  }, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>']
  }, ['responseHeaders']);
```

Before you ask, I use `<all_urls>` in `manifest.json` permissions and it works if I do it via the basic `content_scripts` API.

Should I file a chrome issue or is it a problem in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest):

> Note that for some of the supported schemes the set of available events might be limited due to the nature of the corresponding protocol. For example, for the "**file:**" scheme, **only** `onBeforeRequest`, `onResponseStarted`, `onCompleted`, and `onErrorOccurred` may be dispatched.